# Will enabling RDS IAM auth disable the password auth automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I am following this tutorial to enable RDS postgres IAM auth for the master user: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam/

The master user currently uses password auth. One thing I am not sure about is: if I enable the IAM auth for this master user, can I still use password to talk to RDS? Can we have these two types of auth working at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For PostgreSQL, if the IAM role (rds_iam) is added to the master user,
> IAM authentication takes precedence over Password authentication so
> the master user has to log in as an IAM user.

So you cannot login with your actual DB password for the users which you enabled rds-iam role. All other DB user accounts(where rds-iam role is not enabled) can login with actual DB password.

Refer AWS Documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html#UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Limitations

Comment: Note that AWS is talking specifically about the master user here, but this was my experience for *every* user. You can have other users that use password authentication, but AFAIK, you can't have an account that works with both IAM and password authentication simultaneously.

Comment: I can confirm this happens not only for the master user, I granted IAM access to a db user and I'm basically locked out of the database now, there was no warning in the docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.DBAccounts.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can still use both at once, it is just disabled by default.

> You don't need to store user credentials in the database, because authentication is managed externally using IAM. You can also still use standard database authentication.

Quote taken from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html

Comment: Sorry, I am bit confused. Can you elaborate this?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, so basically IAM authentication is a feature, not an option. By enabling this it does replace normal user based authentication. Also worth noting if it’s limitations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html

Comment: If I understand correctly, enabling the IAM auth for a specific DB user will disable its password auth automatically, right? If so, why does `Yes you can still use both at once` mean?

Comment: Added link, your IAM user does not replace your DB user, so rest assured both will still work :)

Comment: Do you mean it should work to connect to my postgres user after granting rds_iam to another user? because I just did this and it doesn't, unable to login to postgres user at all now

Comment: @ChrisWilliams that link specifically says that at least for Postgresql that isn't true. *For PostgreSQL, if the IAM role (rds_iam) is added to a user (including the RDS master user), IAM authentication takes precedence over password authentication, so the user must log in as an IAM user.*

Answer (score -2):

I can confirm you can use both, steps:

1. Enabled IAM Authentication
2. Login with your mysql -h rdsendpoint -u user -p

--- Take it a step further ---

3. Login with a different user mysql -h rdsendpoint -u user2 -p

--- Another step further ---

4. Reset the client machine AWS Credentials $ aws configure and
5. Remove any IAM roles on an EC2 (if you're testing from one)
6. Login with your mysql -h rdsendpoint -u user -p

Confirmed all work